# How to fetch array values using jq

Tags: linux, jq, aws-cli

file.json

```
{
   "Groups":[
      
   ],
   "Instances":[
      {
         "AmiLaunchIndex":0,
         "ImageId":"ami-id",
         "InstanceId":"i-123548874",
         "InstanceType":"c5.4xlarge",
         "KeyName":"kay",
         "LaunchTime":"dateValue",
         "Monitoring":{
            "State":"disabled"
         },
         "Placement":{
            "AvailabilityZone":"zone value",
            "GroupName":"",
            "Tenancy":"default"
         },
         "PrivateDnsName":"ip address",
         "PrivateIpAddress":"10.245.247.21",
         "ProductCodes":[
            
         ], 
and more json...
```

There is only one item in the array.I want to fetch **InstanceId** and **PrivateIpAddress** from json. I am using below command to fetch value:

```
file.json | jq -r .Instances[].InstanceId
file.json | jq -r .Instances[].PrivateIpAddress
```

But I am getting nothing in the response.

I have tried various ways mentioned in other stack overflow questions and I am still not getting proper response.

I am expecting below response

```
i-123548874
10.245.247.21
```

Comment: Quote your jq filter and put the file name at the end, like so: `jq -r '.Instances[].InstanceId' file.json`. Or if you want/need to pipe in the contents of the file, output it using `cat` for instance (the file name alone won't dump its content): `cat file.json | jq ...`. Your filter by itself seems okay.

Comment: "-r: command not found" getting this message.

Comment: Did you miss `jq` up front?

Comment: `cat file.json | jq -r .Instances[].InstanceId`  works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file.json | jq -r .Instances[].PrivateIpAddress
10.245.247.21

$ cat file.json | jq -r .Instances[].InstanceId
i-123548874
```

Or

```
$ jq -r .Instances[].PrivateIpAddress file.json
10.245.247.21

$ jq -r .Instances[].InstanceId file.json
i-123548874
```